# Where can I get themes and eye-candy for my desktop?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, appearance, gtk

Apart from those themes in the repository and Gnome-look.org, are there other places to get themes for my Ubuntu Desktop?

Also, are there any 3rd party repositories of themes and other eye-candy?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/) is where I got a lot of nice themes and tips for customization. Plus they maintain a PPA with modding/utility apps.They also have a PPA `ppa:webupd8team/themes` ([How to add PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)) specifically for themes.

Comment: +1 That's what I'm talking about. A PPA of themes.

Comment: Check this out for some more themes: https://launchpad.net/~bisigi/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 8):

Here you'll find some Ubuntu related art:
http://browse.deviantart.com/?q=gallery%3Aubuntu-artists%2F24290476

And here, Ubuntu awareness material (and release countdown buttons) :
http://spreadubuntu.neomenlo.org/

Regards!

Comment: +1 I was more interested in themes than images but this is a great link, Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some themes PPAs:

- https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox
- https://launchpad.net/~elementaryart/+archive/ppa
- https://launchpad.net/~elegant-gnome/+archive/ppa

All of those are amazing themes. The first PPA comes with the updated Ubuntu Light Themes backported from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 4):

This weblog does alot of [customization](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/) tutorials and various other ubuntu thematics related topics.

Plus its in England

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link. Guess me modding you up means you're heading off again :).

Comment: Check out the "Eye Candy" menu near the top of the home page. It will narrow things down to what you are looking for!

Answer (score 3):

[GNOME-LOOK.ORG](http://gnome-look.org/)
I have been using this for so many years, their collection is just unmatched in terms of volume and quality.

Comment: The OP already mentioned gnome-look.org.

Answer (score 2):

Reddit pics (http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/) is sometimes a good source for artistic, odd, funny, or bueautiful images that make good desktop backgrounds. Here are a few I've found (I especially like landscapes):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPY3v.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBl94l.jpg

http://science.nationalgeographic.com/wallpaper/science/photos/canyons-gallery/canyon-de-chelly/

Comment: +1 These are nice wallpapers. I was mainly looking for themes as they are harder to find on line but thanks for the valuable links.

Answer (score 1):

And the "Granddaddy" of them all is gnomelook.org---not a PPA, but when you can just take a .tar & drop it on Appearance--why a PPA?

Comment: A PPA because you get updates without having to constantly check the website to see if there's a new version...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this eye-candy project from France, it's amazing:
http://www.bisigi-project.org/?page_id=8&lang=en

It works great, I didn't have any problems with the themes and they are complete, meaning that you have their icons not only on your desktop but also in nautilus file browser.

I apologize in case an answer from above has already mentioned it.