# Where to find great themes?

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get themes and eye-candy for my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2502/where-can-i-get-themes-and-eye-candy-for-my-desktop)

Other than the normal sites (IE: Gnome-Look, Webup8, OMGU, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/2502/18612

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can find some good things in http://art.gnome.org/ or http://gnome-themes.org/

Answer (score 7):

[gnome look](http://www.gnome-look.org)

Answer (score 3):

All of the above, in addition to [deviantART](http://www.deviantart.com). Most higher quality themes (of any type) are found on deviantART, and while it has its share of low-quality stuff, it's fairly easy to filter.

Answer (score 2):

[Deviant Art](http://www.deviantart.com/) has a [section for Gnome themes](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/linuxutil/desktopenv/gnome/?order=9).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are not aware of it, there are some fairly nice ones available in the repository,I recommend you try the community-themes and shiki-colors, shiki-colors is quite elegant I think. You may very well not need any more with these. the community-themes package contains these: Kin, Night Impression, Impression, Hanso, Turrican, Homosapien, Sorbet and Wasp-Murrine. Sorbet is a favourite of mine, I only modify the window border, using the one from Radiance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [themes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/themes/+packages) (it currently holds probably the most popular themes/icons that don't have a PPA yet - Faenza has a PPA but ignore the main Faenza icon theme in the PPA, it's there just because some themes depend on it)

Answer (score 1):

[Bisigi Project](http://www.bisigi-project.org/?page_id=6&lang=en) offers some nice themes for gnome environment. Check if there is any u like ;)

Answer (score 1):

The community-themes package contains additional themes by the Ubuntu community.

To install it, search the Software Center for *community-themes* or run `sudo apt-get install community-themes` in a terminal.