# What GIMP tutorials are available?

Tags: gimp

Where can I get some GIMP tutorials?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- [Gimp.org](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/)
- [Gimpology](http://gimpology.com/)
- [Libre Graphics Magazine](http://libregraphicsmag.com/)
- [Mygimptutorial](http://mygimptutorial.com/)
- [Grokking the GIMP](http://gimp-savvy.com/BOOK/)
- [Gimpvids](http://gimpvids.com/)
- [Ghuj.com](http://www.ghuj.com/)
- [Gimp.pixtuts](http://gimp.pixtuts.com/)
- [Gimpworks](http://gimpworks.blogspot.com/)
- [Gimpusers](http://www.gimpusers.com/tutorials)
- [Gimp.wisdomplug](http://www.gimp.wisdomplug.com/)
- [Brainsongimp](http://brainsongimp.blogspot.com/)
- [Meetthegimp](http://meetthegimp.org/)
- [Gimp-tutorials](http://gimp-tutorials.net/)
- [Tux-Radar](http://www.tuxradar.com/gimp)
- [Tutorial Geek](http://tutorialgeek.blogspot.com/search/label/Gimp)
- [Iki.fi](http://www.iki.fi/wwwwolf/graphtips/gimptutorials/)
- [Halley.cc](http://halley.cc/photo/multexp/)
- [MultiGimpTutorials](http://www.youtube.com/user/MultiGimpTutorials)
- [Gimpguru](http://gimpguru.org/Tutorials/)
- [Weeaks](http://tweeaks.com/design/10-amazing-gimp-sig-tutorials-for-advanced-users/)
- [Emptyeasel](http://emptyeasel.com/art-tutorials/gimp-help/)
- [Surfnlearn](http://www.surfnlearn.com/view_tutorials/GIMP/All/)
- [Vandelaydesign](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/design/gimp-tutorials/)
- [Deviantart](http://browse.deviantart.com/resources/tutorials/gimp/)
- [Creativenerds](http://creativenerds.co.uk/tutorials/50-design-tutorials-for-mastering-gimp/)
- [Gimptalk](http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/forum/28-gimp-tutorials-and-tips/)
- [Gimptalk User Submitted](http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/forum/34-users-submitted-gimp-tips-tutorials/)
- [Noupe](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/30-exceptional-gimp-tutorials-and-resources.html)
- [Unixmen](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/1583-30-great-tutorials-for-gimp)
- [Templates.com](http://www.templates.com/blog/15-gimp-video-tutorials-create-easily/)
- [Ijaar.com](http://ijaar.com/30-excellent-gimp-tutorials-for-beginners/)
- [Sixrevisions](http://sixrevisions.com/graphics-design/gimp_video_tutorials/)
- [Allgraphicdesign](http://www.allgraphicdesign.com/gimpsitesresources.html)
- [Techdrivein](http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/09/12-useful-gimp-video-tutorials-for.html)
- [Qbrushes](http://blog.qbrushes.net/best-40-gimp-tutorials/)

Answer (score 15):

There's always [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=gimp%20tutorials%20for%20beginners&aq=0&oq=gimp%20tutorials) .

[image: YouTube Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

The GIMP User Group has some as well: http://gug.criticalhit.dk/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=4a4ed54fbecb7a9f84e1bb53c8f78bda

Answer (score 4):

I found "grokking-the-gimp" very helpful as an all inclusive learning tool and reference. You can install it as a package from the Ubuntu repositories. For the most part, the online tutorials are task versus application function oriented like Grokking the GIMP, which can make them superior if they cover the task you which to accomplish. Both have their place.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.giesdesign.com/ is an italian blog with great and simple Gimp tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn a bit more about image processing (particularly photographic retouching), you can head on over to my GIMP tutorials (there's a couple of basic ones, and a few that are a little more advanced):

[Getting Around in GIMP](http://blog.patdavid.net/p/getting-around-in-gimp.html)