# How to install Windows 7 theme with GNOME Shell?

Tags: 11.04, windows-7, gnome, themes

I installed GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 11.04 and logged in with it. But when I try to install the Windows theme, it complains that

> Gnome desktop session is required

Anyone knows why this is? Is there another way to make it look like Windows?

Software Center shows gnome-shell installed (which included gnome-session manager). I'm installing windows theme downloaded from [here](http://web.lib.sun.ac.za/ubuntu/files/help/theme/gnome/win7-setup.sh).

Comment: Similar question but for Unity: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50581/is-there-an-ubuntu-theme-available-to-make-it-look-like-windows-7/96347#96347

Comment: False there is a gtk3 theme wich look s similar to the gtk2 theme . search ambiancew7 theme on sourcefprge net. If you use cinnamon, you could select the ambiancew7 theme and then install the window list group addon and the win7 emulöator +cinnamon menu.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the following line(71) at `win7-setup.sh`:

```
if [ $DESKTOP_SESSION = "gnome" -o $DESKTOP_SESSION = "classic-gnome" ] ; then
```

to

```
if [ $DESKTOP_SESSION = "gnome" -o $DESKTOP_SESSION = "gnome-classic" ] ; then
```

Answer (score 1):

First check that "gnome-session" is installed. Should be since you can log in to your session. But just to be sure, you can check it in Software Center. If not installed try installing it and then try installing your Windows 7 theme again.

If it's installed the some more information about how your installing your windows 7 theme would be good.

Comment: Hi, Yes I believe I have it installed correctly.  Software Center shows gnome-shell installed (which included gnome-session manager).
I'm installing windows theme downloaded from:
http://web.lib.sun.ac.za/ubuntu/files/help/theme/gnome/win7-setup.sh

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the shell script you provided, it contains GnoMenu, which as far as I'm aware, is a Gnome Panel applet. It is possible that it might work with Gnome Panel 3, but I have my doubts. Gnome Panel 2 is no longer available since Gnome 2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The theme that you're trying to install is intended for `gnome2.x` and `gtk2` applications.

This will not work on `gnome3.x` and `gtk3` based applications.

AFAIK there's no `gtk3` theme that looks similar to Windows7,