# is there a theme for ubuntu 11.10 which look like windows-7

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Ubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50581/is-there-an-ubuntu-theme-available-to-make-it-look-like-windows-7)

first of all it is n not a dup
of [Is there an Ubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50581/is-there-an-ubuntu-theme-available-to-make-it-look-like-windows-7)

because is is not working with 11.10

i also tried http://www.howtogeek.com/55985/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7/
 but it is also for the 11.04 
 can anyone help??