# How do I make my desktop look like Windows 7 or 8?

Tags: themes, appearance, colors, xubuntu, animations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Ubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50581/is-there-an-ubuntu-theme-available-to-make-it-look-like-windows-7)

I'm wondering if there is a Windows 7 GTK theme to download out there?

Or maybe a Windows 8 theme?