# How to Make Ubuntu look like Windows Vista?

Tags: themes, windows-vista

Well for Starters, I do know that this sounds weird to want it to look like vista and not windows 7, but I just don't like how win7 looks, that's just me, you can not change me.

I have searched on Google quite a bit looking for this, nothing shows me to make 12.04 look like vista, just win7.

So if you could help me, thanks!

Comment: Don't they look pretty much the same?

Comment: lol omg this question made my rep number thing go up a lot @_@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting Started:

- Re-theme to Windows 7 as per this [AU Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/175828/14356):
- Complete the Vista transformation: Use [this link](http://www.chimerarevo.com/ubuntu-12-04-installare-i-fonts-mac-e-windows-vista/) and google translator

Comment: And I answer to him if U read : and to install windows vista theme use this link and google translator :

http://www.chimerarevo.com/ubuntu-12-04-installare-i-fonts-mac-e-windows-vista/

Comment: This is 99% identical to this answer! http://askubuntu.com/questions/50581/is-there-an-ubuntu-theme-available-to-make-it-look-like-windows-7

Comment: all right man ,so as he asked for two things :  "I have searched on google quite a bit looking for this, nothing shows me to make 12.04 look like vista, just win7.

    Is there an Ubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 7?"                                                             I gave him the theme for windows 7 and the link for windows vista theme ,wat's wrong with that ?

Comment: Lets try to keep the duplication of material to a minimum - it makes keeping information obsolescence easier to control and overcome.

Answer (score 7):

To make Ubuntu 12.04 look like Windows Vista would take a bunch of time and effort, and you might break your system doing all those changes. As an alternative you can install Kubuntu that is the [KDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE) ([Desktop Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)) specifically modified for Ubuntu, it looks a little like Windows.

[image]

To install Kubuntu (KDE + Ubuntu) type the following command at the Terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

If you prefer a graphical interface to install it you can use Synaptic.

But the recommended way to do that is downloading the Kubuntu ISO. it's like downloading Ubuntu, but instead of using the Unity shell interface it will comes with KDE installed by default. To download the ISO file access [Kubuntu.org](http://kubuntu.org) to get more information about it.

Comment: The KDE Userbase: http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/TweakingPlasma has "A Windows Vista-like sidebar with clock and news"

Comment: If you only want to use Kubuntu, it's best to [get a special Kubuntu installation ISO instead](http://www.kubuntu.org)

Answer (score -1):

If you like Vista's GUI, but don't want to leave Ubuntu then check out [reference article](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-make-ubuntu-look-like-windows-vista.html) with the links to skins, wallpapers, fonts and icons for making Ubuntu look like Vista.

Comment: You shut edit your answer to include the basics steps. As it is, this is a link only answer.