# How to make Latest Ubuntu look like Windows 7

Tags: 13.04, windows-7

For a talk about Linux I will be using Ubuntu to show off how flexible Open Source is, but one of the things I want to do is show Ubuntu with a Windows 7 Theme, which I will then change when a friend just happens to ask "But you are using Windows 7 to talk about Open Source", at that moment I will change the whole theme back to the **default Ubuntu theme** (Unity) which should have a impact on users that have not yet moved to Ubuntu.

Since I will be doing this on 13.04 (Examples for 11.04 up to 12.10 do not work in 13.04) I need a solution for this version. I have tried the following links and between not working and making the whole system unstable (Had to install from scratch) they did not solve my question:

[Is there an Ubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50581/is-there-an-ubuntu-theme-available-to-make-it-look-like-windows-7)

[How to Make Ubuntu look like Windows Vista?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204555/how-to-make-ubuntu-look-like-windows-vista)

So how can I change Ubuntu to a Windows 7 theme in 13.04?