# How can I Customize my ubuntu to look like windows

Tags: installation

How can I customize my Ubuntu 12 to look like windows

Comment: Take a look at Xubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and paste these commands one after one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install win2-7 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Win2-7-theme'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Win2-7-theme'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Win2-7-icons' 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'menu:minimize,maximize,close'
```

[Credit goes here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028896/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite a lot things you'd have to do to make Ubuntu look like windows. I cannot sum them all up here and they are nicely explained in this [post on pcworld.com](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028896/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7.html). That post works on 12.10.

Essentially it includes install icons and a theme and then configuring them:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install win2-7 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Win2-7-theme'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Win2-7-theme'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Win2-7-icons'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'menu:minimize,maximize,close' 
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt indicator-appmenu
```

You can also use XFCE as a desktop (which is a more drastic change if you are not used to changing desktops on Ubuntu).

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install win2-7
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Win2-7-theme'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'menu:minimize,maximize,close' 
metacity --replace
```

You really should read the post linked to above! Your mileage may vary. You should not that the filesystem will of course remain organized as in Ubuntu. Also this only *looks* like windows.

Comment: oops you are late my friend

Comment: why downvote may i  ?

Comment: Your answer is copy-paste. You could at least have tried to explain something or add something of your own. Also there is no such thing in AU as 'being late'. But never mind, I'll revert.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your theme**

Enter this in terminal(ctr+alt+T)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install win2-7
```

You installed Win2-7 theme. to enable it run either one of these

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Win2-7-theme'

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Win2-7-theme'

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Win2-7-icons'
```

**The closest ubuntu like  is Xfce**

Simply run this in terminal to install and see if it fits you

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

There's another answer explaining this:
[How to make Latest Ubuntu look like Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292639/how-to-make-latest-ubuntu-look-like-windows-7)