# Is there a Kubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 2000?

Tags: kubuntu, themes

Is there a Kubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 2000?

I am aware of [Is there an Ubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/q/50581/44876), but I prefer the Microsoft Windows 2000 interface as it barely has any visual effect, and subsequently require less results than more recent versions of Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Open Desktop](http://KDE-look.org), I found  these two themes

[Windows 2000 Theme](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Windows+2000+Theme?content=150).  Theme/Style for KDE 2.1

[Windows 2000 0.1](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Windows+2000?content=117036), KDE Color Scheme KDE4

You can look at the above site for more themes, that might be available.  Hope that helps.