# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at startup and keyboard turns off

Tags: gnome, startup

I have some issues with Ubuntu 18.04 on my Acer Aspire 5742g with a Core i3 CPU and 4GB DDR3 RAM. If needed I will paste the full specs.

Sometimes at startup and immediately after waking up from sleep nothing works. After I select my account and type my password. Sometimes programs like Firefox work, but neither bookmark links nor keyboard typing works. The keyboard is stuck for all programs, and sometimes when I change the typing language it starts to work, sometimes not.

I noticed that sometimes time is needed (a couple of seconds) for everything to get normal.

I've done some customization on my desktop and now it looks like this :

[image]

I installed Ubuntu tweaks and my language bar is also from Ubuntu Software. Could it be the reason for my issues? Or my laptop? Or my only 4GB RAM? The latest Ubuntu updates are installed.

Comment: Why nobody gives me answer?

Comment: this is a shot in the dark but I would suggest launching System Monitor when you start if you can. take a look at it and see what the ram use and the swap use is like. if they are high please post a screen shot of the results.

Comment: I don't think this question is about a software bug. It looks like a hardware issue for which one or more workarounds exist. Also customization of the Ubuntu 18.04 desktop may be an issue that's worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 17.10 and later press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and then type `r` in the pop-up Run a Command window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME Shell without interfering with any already opened windows.

Alternatively you can run the following command to restart GNOME shell by replacing the running window manager:

```
setsid gnome-shell --replace
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again before you close the terminal.

Also customization of the Ubuntu 18.04 desktop may be an issue that's worth looking into. Maybe Ubuntu will not get stuck at startup if you undo the desktop customizations and revert back to the default vanilla Ubuntu 18.04 desktop environment.

Comment: thanks. I made all customizations because I want my ubuntu to look like windows.

Comment: Tell me guys, how I can build or what to use to make UBUNTU/DEBIAN to look like Windows 7 with classic desktop, shortcuts (to make them easy with LMB), toolbars, etc?

Comment: @G-nPetrov [@G-nPetrov Is there an Ubuntu theme available to make it look like Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50581/) + https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Win2-7+Pack?content=113264