# Is there hope for having an ubuntu theme that looks like unity's context-menu theme?

Tags: unity, themes

I like the transparent + gradient + dots theme. Will Canonical implement a system-wide theme that is similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canonical might not. The community might, or you might! If you're interested in this kinda thing, take a look at this question: [How do I make a Theme from scratch for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity)