# How can I create my own ubuntu theme?

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a Theme from scratch for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity)

I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.10.

My question is how can I create my own Ubuntu theme. I'm a coder (html/css/php/sql), so I think I'm capable of creating my own theme, I just need to know where/how to start.

I was hoping someone could point me to the right direction. The basic settings in themes/customize aren't enough for what I need to do.

I'm not even sure whether Unity and Gnome shell share the same themes, but if not, I'd probably go for theme-ing the Unity.

Comment: well, since ubuntu 11.10 will probably have only unity ( and unity 2D ), question is do you want theme for unity (which will be using gnome3 ) or for gnome2 ? Have you tried using unity ?

Comment: I'd therefore go for the former option. I will update the question now. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way would be to go to `/usr/share/themes/`, copy the folder of your favorite theme, and start editing/replacing the images and the colors in the configuration files :p

If you'd rather start from scratch, this seems like a good guide: http://orford.org/gtk/
But notice that this guide is for Gtk2, and Ubuntu 11.10 will use Gtk3 ;)

Comment: URL not found...

Comment: @salihkallai Ubuntu uses Gtk3 now anyway