# Is there a theme creator and/or editor?

Tags: software-recommendation, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a Theme from scratch for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity)

I want to make my own theme, or edit an existing one. But I can't really find an application for Ubuntu 12.10, Unity (6.10.0).

Right now I have a theme (Delorean-dark) that I want to edit, cause of some inconsistencies, and later make my own theme.

Is there a theme application that can make new and edit existing themes?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/59897/how-can-i-create-my-own-ubuntu-theme and http://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity