# ICO or PNG Format?

Tags: files, icons, format, png

Kind of a dumb question, but which file format are ubuntu icons (in apps and dash to dock) are they .png or .ico files? I want to create some icon/themes for ubuntu. But I'm not sure which format to use, also is 256x256 the resolution like in windows?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu has anything to do with "ico" files, it would be "png"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create my own ubuntu theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59897/how-can-i-create-my-own-ubuntu-theme)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Icons in Ubuntu

**Fixed size icons** are usually in **`png`** format (can be viewed with most image viewers).

**Scalable icons** are usually in **`svg`** format (can be viewed with for example `eog`, Eye of Gnome, and can be created and manipulated (and zoomed) with **`inkscape`**).

You can find icons that belong to the desktop environment and the installed application programs in subdirectories of

```
/usr/share/icons/
```

You will find a whole series of resolutions. In my Lubuntu the following commands find resolutions from 8x8 to 512x512. And there are scalable icons, which will be displayed well in any size/resolution (not pixelated).

```
$ cd /usr/share/icons/hicolor

$ ls|sort -n
icon-theme.cache
index.theme
scalable
symbolic
8x8
16x16
20x20
22x22
24x24
28x28
32x32
36x36
40x40
42x42
48x48
64x64
72x72
96x96
128x128
192x192
256x256
512x512
```