# Disk properties in Gnome Files shows a black chart for disk usage on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, nautilus

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and noticed that if I open the Properties window for a disk (not a plain folder) the pie chart intended to show disk usage is all black. On prior versions it used to have different colors for "used" and "free" space.

Testing a clean install on a virtual machine gives the same results so it's not an issue related to the upgrade process. I guess it's related to the theming features added to Ubuntu 22.04.

What could be causing this? Is there an easy way to add the colors back?

[image: Pie chart in Nautilus is all black - there's a faint gray line suggesting it's trying to render the pie slices but you can't see them because they're all the same color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default theme is causing this. Install `gnome-tweaks` from Ubuntu software then go to appearance / applications and change to Adwaita (Default) or some other theme.

It's possible that the theme can be edited to work.  [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59897/how-can-i-create-my-own-ubuntu-theme) is a link about changing/editing themes, but I have not tried doing this.

Comment: Accepted answer as I've been using Adwaita for now and it does work. I filed a bug too, hopefully I'll be able to switch back to Yaru soon: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/2008791