# How can I make a theme and test it easily for Ubuntu (Unity)?

Tags: unity, gtk, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a Theme from scratch for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity)

I'll never say that the Ubuntu Ambiance theme isn't a beautifu theme, but i want to make a new one, i want to try to make a theme for my Unity as well. I searched a lot yesterday but i didn't see nothing useful. Where I have to look to make a theme in GTK3+ and the new theme engine Unico? I need documentation about these and also something about Unity.

Ah, I have another question, now I trying to make a theme changing small parts of text, but I don't know how to restart Unity, Gnome Panel, and GTK, so I must log out and log in everytime I make a change, are there easily method to test a theme? (Don't tell me change the theme because I tryied it but it don't change everything and some color and button remain the same)

Sorry for my bad english, thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/47643/18612

Comment: No, it's too old. I need better help and updated docs and tutorial.

Comment: It's basically the same question, even if it is a little out of date since it doesn't have an answer for GTK+ 3. I'll start a bounty on it.

Comment: ok, I don't need a lot of information, but I want to know where i can find docs about Unico Engine, all possible classes in gtk3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Launchpad page for Unico is located [here](https://launchpad.net/unico), and documentation for GTK+ 3 is located [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/). This is the closest I can find from what was said in the comments.

Comment: the Unico page isn't really detailed but it's ok, thanks