# Change various interface colors

Tags: 11.10, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme)

The default theme is OK for me, would just like to tune some colors, i.e. usually input field background color across all applications.

This was easily discoverable for me in e.g. 11.04 or earlier; where is that option in 11.10 ?

I found some existing answers using some external tools, etc. Is that really the only solution, did Canonical remove the way to adjust basic theme settings for user?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those options no longer exist in Ubuntu 11.10; themes can't be customized in the `Appearance` screen. Please take a look in this on [how to create a new theme for Ocelot](https://askubuntu.com/a/88435/28076).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take this. I realize my question is kind of redundant, I guess I just wanted to really verify that it's just not possible anymore. Well, time to switch away from Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: @mark I believe this is more like the new Gnome design approach.

Comment: doesn't make it better but I value insightfulness, thank you!