# How to create an Icon theme/set for Ubuntu?

Tags: themes, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a Theme from scratch for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity)

I am looking to create an Icon theme for Ubuntu Unity. This is a first time effort, so I was looking for answers from people who have experience in the matter. How do I go about creating an Icon set for Ubuntu? The basics at least.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I go about creating an Icon set for Ubuntu? The basics at least.

Ubuntu uses the [Gnome Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/) (number 9 ) you can follow these to make your Icons fit for the Gnome Desktop. Ubuntu also has guidelines for the Indicators as noted [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators).

Create them using whichever software you prefer, they need to be in .PNG or .SVG

Look at the folder structure of any icon set so you know how you should organize them for them to work. And so you also know what are the names of the icons.

Unity doesn't specifically use a theme it takes on the System Theme.

And lastly use your creativity.

Comment: What is the folder structure? Where do I put icons? Do I just put them in `/usr/share/icons`?

Comment: @Aaron Franke Here is the folder structure/tree-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17IKA8KWftMDd8sZoGJiu9k3o_dewhfBx/view?usp=sharing