# "redmond" theme on kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

Fresh kubuntu 15.04 install (so: using plasma 5.2.2). I happen to like the classic Windows look (it also really confuses people :) ), and in previous releases I've installed the kdeartwork (or some such) package, and it appeared in the Workspace Appearance section of the system settings.

Well, that selection is no longer available, and no additional themes are showing up in what appears to have replaced it ("Workspace Theme").

(Note that this is different from the "Application Style" setting, which sets colors for titlebars etc., which still has a Windows 9X selection, but that's not what I'm looking for).

Help?

Comment: did you enable Universe repos?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled Universe repos. And check the package with:

```
apt-cache policy kdeartwork
```

Or other solutions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

Name: kdeartwork

Description:

themes, styles and other artwork from the official KDE release.

Latest version: 4:15.04.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1

Release: vivid (15.04)

Level:  base

Repository: main

Other versions of "kdeartwork" in Vivid:

Repository area base Universe version 4:14.12.3-0ubuntu1

PPA: Mint Import 4:4.14.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04~ppa1

Comment: I have already installed kdeartwork (see my post!). both universe and backports are already in my sources lists. Thanks though!

Comment: what are you trying to do now then? Because I'm confused. You want desktop look like WinXP or some?

Comment: Yes, i do. I'm change-averse :)

Comment: (the root cause of the problem is that package kdeartwork in 15.04 does not contain anything:
 
`$ dpkg-query --listfiles kdeartwork
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/kdeartwork
/usr/share/doc/kdeartwork/copyright
/usr/share/doc/kdeartwork/changelog.Debian.gz
`

Comment: Also: backports provides *newer* versions of packages to *older* releases; I need the opposite!

Comment: you have to wait there's no yet much themes currently for 15.04 there's nothing to do about it. After some time it'll be there.

Comment: i'm a kernel guy, but I'm sure I can learn to make my own themes. Any pointers on how to go about it?

Comment: go here http://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity