# Can I use GNOME2 themes in GNOME3?

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get themes and eye-candy for my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2502/where-can-i-get-themes-and-eye-candy-for-my-desktop)

I have been using Ubuntu for years. I love it and am a big fan of gnome 2x and gtk 2x.

I have lots of themes installed which worked on those former versions. However, since the implementation of GNOME3 and GTK3 the old gtk/gnome style themes no longer work.

I went to `usr/share/themes` and noticed that there are major differences in the ways themes are handled. To see the difference you just need look at the Radiance theme and see the difference between the two schemes.

Since there is such a difference, will there be a tool to convert old themes to the new standard or are there more themes on their way?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/2502/18612

Answer (score 0):

A few links for Unity themes:

[Several themes (11.04 but most should support 11.10)](http://www.linoob.com/2011/04/customized-themes-for-ubuntu-11-04/)

[Elementary, Orta, Minty Freshness](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/elementary-orta-and-minty-freshness.html)

[Ongoing work on a very customizable theme](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Incoming/Lucid/Unity%20Theme)