# Is there any place on the internet that houses window themes (as Ubuntu tweak calls them) and gtk themes for ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, themes, 32-bit

I'm wonder if there is like a one-stop place on the internet where I can find all the window themes and gtk themes I could possibly want for Ubuntu. I would like these themes to be compatible with 32 bit 12.10.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2502/where-can-i-get-themes-and-eye-candy-for-my-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/themes-collection-for-ubuntu-1110-unity.html) contains a big themes Collection for Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail/Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal/Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin/Ubuntu 11.10 (Unity, Gnome Shell, GTK3, and GTK2)/Linux Mint 14/13/12.